# Service now SMTP test connection failing even though I am able to test connection from midserver

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to set up SMTP for my service now instance by trying to connect to a specific SMTP host. I am able to test connection from the midserver. But when I try from the service now portal, its failing to connect.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is there any option in service now to make sure this connection is happening via the midserver instance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORJxn.png